# HttpPostedFileBase is null when using AJAX in ASP MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using JQuery.AJAX to upload files to the server in ASP.NET MVC 5.
The code of my view is:

```
<input type="file" size="45" name="file" id="file">
```

The Javascript is:

```
<script>
$('#file').on("change", function () {
    var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));
    CallService(formdata);
});
function CallService(file) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: file,
        cache: false,
        success: function (color) {
            ;
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error occured');
        }
    }); 
}
```

And finally the code of the HomeController.cs:

```
        public ActionResult Index (HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
       ...

    }
```

But everytime the Index action is called, the `HttpPostedFileBase` Object is empty.
I have read all threads about this issue in SO, but could not find an answer. I have entered the right name and it fits with the parameter name in the controller. What is wrong with the code, so that the object is always empty?

Comment: Could it be `data: $(this).serialize(),` instead of `data: { 'file': $(this).serialize() },`.

Comment: Also try [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to intercept requests and see what's actually being sent to the server.

Comment: @RDay Modifying the data hasn't changed anything and it is still null. The result of Fiddler:
Request Count:   1
Bytes Sent:      382  (headers:382; body:0)
Bytes Received:  0  (headers:0; body:0)




RESPONSE BYTES (by Content-Type)
--------------
~headers~: 0

Comment: You need to use `FormData` when uploading files using ajax - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)

Comment: Edit your question with what you have tried - too hard to read in comments.And look again at the link - in particular the ajax options you need to set.

Comment: You still have not included `processData: false,` and `contentType: false,`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have done that now, but it is still null. But I have found another article [here](https://cmatskas.com/upload-files-in-asp-net-mvc-with-javascript-and-c/) and have implemented it and it works. I don't know how to modify my code that it works, but this article is definitely a solution for this problem

Comment: That link is essentially doing just what the link I gave you does except that its a long hand way of adding the files to `FormData`. Do you actually have a `<form>` element containing your `<input type="file" ../>`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, yes, that was exactly the lack in my code. I have inserted it and now it is working. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the right code for this problem:
View:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" size="45" name="file" id="file">
</form>
```

The Javascript:

```
<script>
    $('#file').on("change", function () {
        var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));
        CallService(formdata);
    });

    function CallService(file) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Home")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: file,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (color) {
                ;
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Error occured');
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

And finally the code of the HomeController.cs:

```
public ActionResult Index (HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
   ...
}
```